# WordPress get_terms() function not display custom taxonomy categories for woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

The following code I wrote is supposed to show all the product categories of a wordpress ecommerce website.

```
<?php $categories = get_terms( 
  array(
   'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
   'hide_empty' => 'false',
   'numberposts' => -1)
  );
?>
<?php var_dump($categories); ?>
<?php foreach( $categories as $category ): ?>
 <h4 class="shop-category-name d-inline"><?php echo $category->name; ?></h4>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I'm using it inside a woocommerce hook that is responsible to render the contents before the main shop page, the `woocommerce_before_main_content`. 
I'm not able to get the categories, I will see only one category and the others are not listed. I'm not sure about, but maybe this can be something related to the fact that I'm using the function inside a woocommerce hook? I had a similar issue with the shop page featured image, I was not able to display it because of this motivation and I have modified the code to use the `wc_get_page_ID('pag name')`.

Is there a fix ?

Comment: Remove `'numberposts' => -1`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use it like this in the function, you used for woocommerce hook `woocommerce_before_main_content`

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woo_cats', 20, 0 );
function woo_cats(){
 $cat_args = array(
    'orderby'    => 'name',
    'order'      => 'asc',
    'hide_empty' => false,
);

$product_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', $cat_args );

 if( !empty($product_categories) ){
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($product_categories as $key => $category) {
        echo '<li>';
        echo '<a href="'.get_term_link($category).'" >';
        echo $category->name;
        echo '</a>';
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
 }
}
```

Comment: In a separate function or inside the hook? If inside the hook, I already have the function call inside it.

Comment: I have update my answer, so now you can write this directly in your functions.php. And let me know if it helps